# Multi Select String List Losing value on Save

Tags: acumatica

Version 21.214.

I have made a custom field attribute using the PXStringList attribute as the base class.  It works fine until I set the MultiSelect = true.  The field is cleared when I click Save on the screen.  The field that I have the attribute set onto is a custom field, nvarchar(255).

Here's the code for the attribute:

```
  public class MyCustomAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute() : base() 
    {
        
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        base.CacheAttached(sender);

        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();

        PXResultset<MyCustomTable> results = PXSelect<MyCustomTable,
            Where<MyCustomTable.active, Equal<True>>>
            .Select(sender.Graph);

        foreach (MyCustomTable result in results)
        {
            values.Add(result.ValueID);
            labels.Add(result.Description);
        }
        this._AllowedLabels = labels.ToArray();
        this._AllowedValues = values.ToArray();
    }

}
```

I need to have a multi-select dropdown list that reads the values for the drop down from a table - as you can see above.

TIA!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use Multi-Select Selector https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/01/multi-select-selector.html ?

Comment: ignorance would be the only reason.  Thanks for the link!  I implemented and it's working.